# Easy way to use session in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

i trying to get session in Node.js to working, i reading and trying a lot about session in Node.js, in PHP i can use $_SESSION['key'] = $value; but i can find how its working in Node.js.

i have looking on express-session and its look pretty complex to handle cookies and there using MongoDB or Redis to store session.

so i will ask about somarby can share sample on a easy way to handle session by using ExpressJS?

becures if i use express-session i need to use node-uuid to generante my owen uuid v4 key.

so hope i can be helping here, its what i need to complete my user login.

Comment: express-session is really not that hard and you definitely do not need node-uuid. Why do you think that?

Comment: You don't need to use `MongoDB` or `Redis` store. There are [File stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store).

Comment: I can't find guides for it all guides i have found use a db or use a complex metode, can sombody help widt samples or link to easy and good guides :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) together with [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) for storing the sessions in MongoDB. My code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')({
    session: session
});

var cookieExpiration = 30 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 month
app.use(session({
    // When there is nothing on the session, do not save it
    saveUninitialized: false,
    // Update session if it changes
    resave: true,
    // Set cookie
    cookie: {
        // Unsecure
        secure: false,
        // Http & https
        httpOnly: false,
        // Domain of the cookie
        domain: 'http://localhost:3001',
        // Maximum age of the cookie
        maxAge: cookieExpiration
    },
    // Name of your cookie
    name: 'testCookie',
    // Secret of your cookie
    secret: 'someHugeSecret',
    // Store the cookie in mongo
    store: new mongoStore({
        // Store the cookie in mongo
        url: 'mongodb://localhost/databaseName',
        // Name of the collection
        collection: 'sessions'
    })
}));
```

For all the options of express-sessions, see the docs.

Now you can store all your session data on `req.session`. Everything you put on your session, will also be saved in the MongoDB. Make also sure you are sending your cookie from your front-end, otherwise your session will always be empty.

Comment: Cool, and i replace it with data from MinusFour to "File stores" and now i can work width session, thanks a lot i have learn a lot in this weekend ^^